# Why Amazon Forecast give me error in parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, forecast, amazon-forecast

I'm trying to train a prediction with my sales in TARGET_TIME_SERIES, the prices in RELATED_TIME_SERIES, and the product type in ITEM_METADATA
These are the parameters I set in Featurizations:

```
    {
        "AttributeName": "demand",
        "FeaturizationPipeline": [
            {
                "FeaturizationMethodName": "filling",
                "FeaturizationMethodParameters": {
                    "aggregation": "sum",
                    "backfill": "zero",
                    "frontfill": "none",
                    "middlefill": "zero"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AttributeName": "promotional_price",
        "FeaturizationPipeline": [
            {
                "FeaturizationMethodName": "filling",
                "FeaturizationMethodParameters": {
                    "aggregation": "first",
                    "backfill": "median",
                    "frontfill": "none",
                    "futurefill": "max",
                    "middlefill": "median"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AttributeName": "original_price",
        "FeaturizationPipeline": [
            {
                "FeaturizationMethodName": "filling",
                "FeaturizationMethodParameters": {
                    "aggregation": "first",
                    "backfill": "median",
                    "frontfill": "none",
                    "futurefill": "max",
                    "middlefill": "median"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But it gives me an error:

```
We were unable to train your predictor.
Invalid featurization parameters : {original_price=[frontfill=none, aggregation=first], promotional_price=[frontfill=none, aggregation=first]}.
```

I don't understand. This parameters are from documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find that it works if I remove parameters "aggregation" and "futurefill"